# Date not working as specified in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, date, laravel-blade

I am currently doing a project in my project I want to show date/month/only two digit of year but I can't do this.The date are in database and its in `yyyy-mm-dd H-i-s` format Here is my Code

```
    <p class="text-lg">Meeting request sent to
    <strong>{{ (!empty($provider_detail->first_name)) ? $provider_detail->first_name : '' }} {{ (!empty($provider_detail->last_name)) ? $provider_detail->last_name : '' }}</strong></br>
   {{ (!empty($booking->booking_date)) ?  date("y/m/d",$booking->booking_date) : '' }}
```

It shows error.

```
ErrorException in 32beed24f6cd306408a9dd85ca2812a4630c92ec.php line 20:
A non well formed numeric value encountered (View: /home/devtqdyp/public_html/syncopp/resources/views/frontends/booking-successful.blade.php)
```

Please help me solving this.
Thank you

Comment: Please show the error.

Comment: Does `$booking->booking_date` come from the database? i.e. its in `yyyy-mm-dd` format?

Comment: Yes its come from database. No its in dd-mm-yyyy format @RiggsFolly

Comment: updated my question @Chris Cousins

Comment: No sir. It gives me other time. My time will be 16/10/25 but it gives me  69/12/31. @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your date is formatted as you say i.e. `16/10/25` i.e. `yy/mm/dd` then your date needs to be reformatted with `-` instead of `/` for `strtotime()` to correctly interpret it as a European date like this

```
date('y/m/d',strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$booking->booking_date)))
```

Comment: No sir. The same problem occurs @RiggsFolly

Comment: Then please show us exactly what is in `$booking->booking_date`

Answer (score -1):

bookig_date is in numeric value or string ?

Try to change

```
date("y/m/d",$booking->booking_date)
```

to

```
date("y/m/d", strtotime($booking->booking_date))
```

Comment: i TRIED YOUR CODE BUT IT DOES NOT GIVE ME SPECIFIC result. It returns 69/12/31 where as the date will be 16/10/25 @EkinOf. The booking_date is string

Comment: i TRIED YOUR CODE BUT IT DOES NOT GIVE ME SPECIFIC result. It returns 69/12/31 where as the date will be 16/10/25 @RiggsFolly.. The booking_date is string